# How do I set up a bootstrap in reactjs to be responsive?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with the 'card' in the react bootstrap. The point is, they aren't responsive.
By resizing the browser window, they're still all on one line, which looks ugly.
I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with CardGroup. Can it be done in a different way to get a similar effect?
That it was readable and nice!

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey={0}>
            <CardGroup className="card-deck text-center">
                {allPost[0].post.map((item, i) =>
                    <Card key={i} bg='dark' text='white' >                      
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{item.title}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-3 text-muted">
                                {item.data} - {item.displayName}
                            </Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                                {item.text}  
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Card.Footer >
                                {(item.comments.length>0)?( //if there are any comments                             
                                <>
                                    <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="btn btn-outline-light mx-auto" eventKey={item} > 
                                        {/* Click here to see comments */}
                                            Kliknij aby zobaczyć komenarze 
                                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={item}>
                                        <>
                                            {
                                                item.comments.map((com, is) => 
                                                    <Card key={is} bg='dark' text='white' >
                                                            <Card.Body>
                                                                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-3 text-muted">
                                                                    {com.displayName} {com.data}
                                                                </Card.Subtitle>
                                                                <Card.Text>
                                                                    {com.text} 
                                                                </Card.Text>
                                                            </Card.Body>       
                                                        </Card>
                                                    )
                                            }
                                        </>         
                                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                                </> 
                                ):(
                                <>
                                    <Card bg='dark' text='white'>
                                        {/* Add a comments - soon*/}
                                        Dodaj komenarz
                                    </Card>
                                </>    
                                )}
                            </Card.Footer>           
                        </Card.Body>     
                    </Card>
                )}
            </CardGroup>
        </Accordion>
```

Photos:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2LEE.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1kHM.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRBZs.png)

On the third picture you can see that when you zoom in on one element by showing the comments ("Kliknij aby zobaczyć komenarze"), the others are also enlarged.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have an import statement to 'react-bootstrap' for the card elements. When importing the card you should receive all the responsive functionality. Make sure you're importing Accordion, CardGroup, Card etc.

Comment: if something wasn't happening, it would display an error
in the console, as well as in VScode, I have empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your cards inside Row tag. Apply grid to row, so they will be responsive. The raw html will look like this.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Official documentation for that is https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#using-grid-markup